# Is using experimental flags in node js production bad practice?

Tags: node.js, npm

Our team is considering using the `type:"modules"` for our new project so that we will be able to use some ES features like imports. But when importing local modules you will have to explicitly tell node the file extension. `import test from './test.js'` like this.

But node js have an experimental flag `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node` that let's you import local modules without their file extensions. Is this implementation considerd a bad practice in production ?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Definitely. Experimental features are not fully part of the toolset and could be modified/removed at any time without warning. What is it that these experimental features provide that you couldn’t avoid today??

Comment: Like mentioned above it was only so we would be able to use imports without a file extension but after the answers it seems like a bad idea using experimental flags. Specially for this small feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimental features are experimental because they are not yet decided by the community to be a part of the actual features of a language. This can result in the changes being removed which will cause many bugs in your code.